# Does unit tests using microsoft fakes work on community edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I am writing unit tests that use MS Fakes mainly shims on VS2015 enterprise. I understand that for using fakes enterprise edition is required. However, rest of my team is using Community edition. Now if I generate fakes on my machine and write tests involving them, are they supposed to run on machines of rest of the team that is using community edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, anyone interacting with fakes needs to have an Enterprise license.